# Is it correct to call a method inside a Property Setter?

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application I'm working on I came across following code snippet;

```
public int SomeInteger
{
    get { return _someInteger; }
    set
    {
        _someInteger= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SomeInteger");
        SomeIntegerChanged();
    }
}
```

As you can see, inside the property setter a method is called. Is this approach correct or is there any better way to do in MVVM pattern WPF?

As above code snippet is a sample, actually the property setter might load a `DataTable` when the property changes which might be time consuming. I tried to make the application asynchronous using `async` and `await` but above scenarios causes problems since `async` and `await` doesn't have asynchronous property concept.

I also got across a way to bind a event to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and by checking which property triggers the event and call the method. But looking for any other alternatives.

Comment: I really think your last paragraph describes the correct way (making the event handler async and using the async loading methods).

Answer (score 6):

> Is this approach correct or is there any better way to do in MVVM pattern WPF?

This is, unfortunately, the common and accepted MVVM pattern across all of C#. I say "unfortunately" because this pattern does run into problems. It is based on events - which are problematic just on their own - and it also causes an *immediate update*, which in many cases is not desired.

For one example, sometimes it's desirable to have two properties that are mutually dependent - when the user changes one, the other one changes in relation to it - and this can cause problems since there's no way to distinguish "user changes" from "code changes".

For another example, sometimes you can end up with a whole tree of dependent properties, and it can take some time for all the changes to propagate through and stop interfering with each other.

More modern MVVM approaches like the *atomically-updated single source of truth* with *single-directional data flow* (as popularized by Redux) avoid the above problems. There is a C# Redux implementation; I don't know how easy it is to use. In my own [CalculatedProperties library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties), I built my own "invalidation queue" to work around this, which [defers all `PropertyChanged` updates](https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties/wiki/How-It-Works#notification) until after the entire system's new steady-state is calculated.

> I tried to make the application asynchronous using async and await but above scenarios causes problems since async and await doesn't have asynchronous property concept.

True. In particular, you can't "asynchronously get" a property. And this makes sense in the MVVM world; when WPF is updating the screen, and it asks your VM for a data value, then your VM can't say "hold on, I'll get it in a minute". WPF needs to know that value *now* so it can update the screen *now*.

Hooking up an asynchronous event handler is one way of kicking off asynchronous work when the value changes; that approach is fine. Usually, the presence of `SomeIntegerChanged` implies that there is a "changed" event *specifically for that property*, so hooking into `PropertyChanged` with string comparisons is probably the harder way to do it.

For more on asynchronous properties with MVVM, see my [article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, calling the methods in the Setter is okay. Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` for property change notifications in WPF is the correct way, and adding the call to the Setter is the default way to implement it.

The call to `SomeIntegerChanged();` depends a bit on what the method does (and if it's even required given you already implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Using properties as a consumer should have as little side-effects as possible, and generally should be simple operations. There's a nice guide on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property) about that topic.

You should also avoid using strings of property names as parameters, in your case the call to `OnPropertyChanged` should look like this: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeInteger));`

Answer (score 2):

A property setter shouldn't kick off a long-running operation. It should simply set the value of a backing field and perhaps call a fast synchronous method that returns just almost immediately. Please refer to @Stephen Cleary's [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) for more information.

If you need to call an asynchronous whenever `SomeInteger` gets set, you could for example hook up an `async` event handler for the `PropertyChanged` event, e.g.:

```
this.PropertyChanged += async (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SomeInteger))
    {
        await SomeAsyncMethod();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would caution against premature optimisation.

Don't complicate your solution any more than is necessary.

If the change is immediate then there's no problem putting what you like in a setter.

Dependent property changes are an occasional requirement but also not usually a big deal.

If you have a long process needs to start then that sounds like it should be something discrete. You should initiate that processing on a separate thread and or decouple the processing. You could just start up a fire and forget thread ( not terribly elegant ).

You can decouple processing using service calls, message queues like msmq or RabbitMQ or pub sub. There are many pub sub approaches - a simple implementation being mvvmlight's messenger or prism's eventaggregator. More sophisticated would be NServiceBus or even Windows Workflow. If events are involved then weak events are preferable.